# Java, This as argument

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, this

I am trying to build a class that needs to pass itself to another, but I always get a `NullPointerException` when I try this. What should I check out first? I use netbeans and checked with a breakpoint, but the object is correct, not a null.

Code

```
class Kartya {
...
  public void setVisible(boolean bool) {
    MainJFrame.slotpool.addKGepSlots(this);
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jatek.kartya.Kartya.setVisible(Kartya.java:193)
    at jatek.jatekos.EmberiJatekos.lapHozzaad(EmberiJatekos.java:66)
    at gui.MainJFrame.huz(MainJFrame.java:88)
    at gui.MainJFrame.ujJatek(MainJFrame.java:57)
    at gui.MainJFrame.<init>(MainJFrame.java:29)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:37)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: can you show us the code and the Exception Stacktrace ?

Comment: Obviously `MainJFrame.slotpool` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainJFrame.slotpool` is null...